# Cycle in dependencies between targets 'FBReactNativeSpec' and 'Yoga'; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

Whenever I run "react-native run-ios" I'm getting the following build error

> error: Cycle in dependencies between targets 'FBReactNativeSpec' and
> 'Yoga'; building could produce unreliable results. Cycle path:
> FBReactNativeSpec → Folly → glog → YogaKit → Yoga → FBReactNativeSpec
> Cycle details: → Target 'FBReactNativeSpec' has target dependency on
> Target 'Folly' → Target 'Folly' has target dependency on Target 'glog'
> → Target 'glog' has compile command with input
> '/Users/ajayhg/Myproj/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/glog/glog-dummy.m'
> ○ That command depends on command in Target 'YogaKit': script phase
> “Copy generated compatibility header” → Target 'YogaKit' has target
> dependency on Target 'Yoga' → Target 'Yoga' has compile command with
> input '/Users/ajayhg/Myproj/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/Yoga/Yoga-dummy.m'

how to resolve this?

Comment: Has it ever worked? I got the same issue and restarted my macbook and it "solved" it, only to come back again a few days later.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by doing ⌘+Shift+K and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant thread [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31034).

It appears as though Firebase adds a script phase in an order that creates a dependency loop. You can fix it (laboriously, after every `pod install`) by going to XCode > Pods (in the left bar) > FBReactNativeSpec and moving [CP-User] Generate Specs up above the Headers script(s).

Comment: it worked for me thanks man. i had a dependency for which I have to do this everytime. can't we have a way o create a patch for this pod.

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same problem on our app, but unfortunately no solution yet.

Known workaronds are:

1. Switch to legacy build system. It doesn't react on those "fake" cycles
2. Clean and rebuild usually helps. If not, then try to clean and reinstal cocoapods.